# ReactPHP QueryResult Optimization?

Tags: php, reactphp

I would like to know if the result of **QueryResult** is efficient and use well because I just used this lib and I don't know it too well and I would like to know if I respected the code by defining the **resultRows** response with **$data** in the callable and then returning it in the function. I would like to know if I have respected the priorities and if you have any ideas for code **optimization** or anything else.

regards, Nicolas.

```
public function getAllDataFrom(string $table)
{
    $name = strtolower($this->getName());
    $data = null;
    $loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $connection = new \React\MySQL\Factory($loop);
    $my = $connection->createLazyConnection(Utils::USER . ':' . Utils::PASSWORD . '@' . Utils::HOST . ':3306/' . Utils::BASE);
    $my->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name='" . $name . "'")->then(static function(QueryResult $queryResult) use ($my, &$data) {
        $my->quit();
        $data = $queryResult->resultRows;
        return $queryResult->resultRows;

    });
    $loop->run();
    return $data[0] ?? [];
}
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Hi, how parameterized queries with my query ? @Cid

Comment: There is an example on their [github](https://github.com/friends-of-reactphp/mysql#query) : `$my->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = ?", $name)`

Comment: Thanks you so much for your time sir. @Cid